# React native localNotificationSchedule not working for multiple date and time in a loop

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-push-notification

I have tried to call localNotificationSchedule function to show different messages in different times in forEach loop and it works for android but in ios only triggered last notification in the loop.

Any ideas?

```
forEach((id) => {

      if (!MainStore.pushNotificationsActive[id]) {
        const notification = MainStore.notifications[id]
        console.log('Currently setting', notification)
        const messageToDisplay = notification.reminder_message.includes('[Name]') ? notification.reminder_message.replace('Hi [Name], ', '') : notification.reminder_message

        if (MainStore.userProfile.field_withdrawn == true) {
          console.log('======notifications stoped======')
          PushNotification.cancelAllLocalNotifications()
        } else {
          console.log('=======notifications start=====')
          const date = Date.parse(notification.reminder_start_date)

          PushNotification.localNotificationSchedule({
            id: String(id),
            message: messageToDisplay,
            playSound: true,
            date: new Date(date)
          })
          MainStore.pushNotificationsActive[id] = true
        }
      }
    })
```

Comment: Can you check the 'date' value, is that same ?

Comment: based on the info he provided it seems it works on Android, so it should not be same for different notifications

Comment: @JebinBenny date values are different for different notifications

Comment: @DNA.h yes this works on Android and triggered all the notifications but on iOS triggered last notification in the loop

Comment: @ManojAlwis Is it a loop? or function?

Comment: @JebinBenny. it is forEach loop

Comment: @ManojAlwis Did you check that, this loop is iterating? I mean which array are you looping here? I can't see any array here.

Comment: @JebinBenny, yes it's iterating in Android and this issue only getting for iOS.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys i found a solution, iOS allows maximum 60 local schedule notifications and when i reduce my notification count to 60 it works.